# Moving Z points according to distance to a ref point

Tags: c#, math, 3d, geometry

The objective is to have a torsion effect on a 3D object.

As you can see on the image, I try to create a torsion according to the moved (yellow) point in the Z direction.

Thanks to the efficient solution of Fredy here [How to get a parabola shape according to a moved point and nearest points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70520604/how-to-get-a-parabola-shape-according-to-a-moved-point-and-nearest-points)
I can calculate the delta on 2-dimensional space but this time as it is 3D, I don't know how to calculate the delta without having a sharp edge of the object.

Here is what I did :

```
        Point3D centroid;
        (originBall as Mesh).GetArea(out centroid); //Selected sphre's centroid (yellow one).

        // takes the vertices which are in the yellow and blue lines.
        var relatedVertices = baseEnt.Vertices.Where(ro => ro.X <= afterBall.BoxMin.X && ro.Y >= beforeBall.BoxMax.Y).ToList(); 

        //Gets the max distance between the centroid and related vertices.
        var maxDistance = relatedVertices .Max(ro => ro.DistanceToCentroid);

        double distance = 0;
        foreach (var item in relatedVertices)
        {
            distance = Point3D.Distance(item, centroid);
           
            item.Z -= delta - (delta * (distance * distance) / (maxDistance * maxDistance));
        }
```

This works in 2-dimension but in this case, I need more parameters I think.
As you can see in the resulting image, there is a wall in the middle of the object.

Any idea, please?

[image: Moving in the Z direction]

[image: Result]

Comment: So in your example, do you want a faster falloff in the X or do you want there to be a same slope in both X and Y directions? The way you are doing it, the falloff would be the same in the X and Y direction, so the fact you have a rectangle as the bounds would lead to that edge

Comment: I want there to be the same slop in both x and Y directions. I mean as you can see in the resulting image, the bottom (horizontal) wall is much less important and won't bother the foot. I want to have a vertical wall like the horizontal one. So like a torsion effect if the insole was bended by hand.

Comment: If you want the same slope, you are not selecting enough vertices in the X axis to have the desired affect. You'll need to make sure that the vertices you are modifying in the X axis are the same length as the Y axis

Comment: Is not possible to have a math function to have a bending effect? Saying to have the same slop, I mean to have a little delta on the min Y point and the max delta on the top Y point.

Comment: It is possible, it depends on if you want the same, as you say, delta for both the X and Y axis, or if they can be different (ie for your example, the X would have to fall off faster since the length of the X axis you are modifying is smaller than the Y)

Comment: it doesn't matter if they are not the same.  Just to have a torsion effect without sharp walls will be sufficiant.

Comment: Then break what you're doing into X and Y components and weight the Z based on that. OR use a trigonometric function with how you currently have it

Comment: Actually, my problem is that I am not good enough at math. I need the function. In C#, I can apply if I have a function. Like on the answer of Fredy which I shared in my question, if I have a function, it would be the solution.

Comment: Hi @CoskunOzogul! Thanks for your message. I hope you're fine too! I have read several times your new question but I'm afraid not to understand your aim nor why the resulting object seems to be broken. Anyway, by comparing the formulas, I see you took a distance (in the loop) where I would have taken a coordinate. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: @Fredy, imagine an A4 paper on a table and fixed a vertical and a horizontal line like the blue lines in the first image.  And imagine you bend it from the top-left point as shown in the first image. If you pull the top-left point 5 cm in Z-direction, other points will follow it but there will not be a wall like in the resulting image. In a two-dimensional space, your function works perfectly. But in a 3-dimensional space, I couldn't find a working function.

Comment: @CoskunOzogul I can imagine that. What do the 3 little spheres represent in the second image?

Comment: @CoskunOzogul What you call "wall" is this discontinuity as if the object became broken? The formula can't "break" the object. One thing that can do that is the selection method, with the condition: ro.X <= afterBall.BoxMin.X && ro.Y >= beforeBall.BoxMax.Y. If your vertices don't match when the function reaches 0, this may cause a discontinuity. Also, what we can do is a generalisation of the formula as follow: item.Z -= delta - (delta * (distanceX * distanceY) / (maxDistanceX * maxDistanceY)); Obviously, you'll have to adapt the distanceX and maxDistanceX and ...Y all 4 parameters.

Comment: @Fredy, the other three points shouldn't be here. They are not calculated.

Comment: Yes, what I call "wall" is vertical discontinuity. Because of the lower distance to the moving point.  I try your new formula and keep you informed. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: @Fredy, it doesn't make what I need exactly but you gave me a great idea again. I made it work by decreasing Z values by reverse logic in a second loop. Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: @CoskunOzogul, it's great! Thanks for the update!